# In which directions can I direct Gust of Wind?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I recently played in a session where Gust of Wind was used in a way I had not seen before, and I wanted to see if my gut instinct on whether that was actually how Gust works.

Gust of Wind states:

> As a bonus action, you can change the line's direction.

The line is established in the casting, but I am wondering what the valid choices for direction are. In the session I played, the caster changed the direction of the wind to perpendicular to the original line. See below:

[image: Depiction of direction change]

I had been operating under the impression that you could only change the direction the wind emanates from you (the caster). I.E. move the wind from coming out your front to coming out your back.

**What are legal changes to Gust of Wind I can make using the bonus action clause?**

Comment: Where are you quoting that version of the spell description from? It doesn't match the official description of the spell.

Comment: Re: the OP's comment on my answer, I think it was from here, which is the first Google result for "dnd gust of wind": http://dnd5e.wikia.com/wiki/Gust_of_Wind

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## You choose any direction emanating from you.

The text of the spell establishes that the line emanates from you in a certain direction and that's the direction the wind blows (emphasis mine).

> A line of strong wind 60 feet long and 10 feet wide *blasts from you in a direction you choose* for the spell's duration. Each creature that starts its turn in the line must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be pushed 15 feet away from you *in a direction following the line.*

You can use a bonus action to change that direction. The line still emanates from you but in a different direction, and that becomes the new direction the wind blows in. Creatures pushed by the wind are always pushed along that line in a direction away from you following the line.

The perpendicular example in your diagram is not a valid use of the spell. A creature can only be pushed parallel to the direction of the line.

As noted by @V2Blast, you have misquoted the spell in your question, and that might be the source of your misunderstanding. The actual text of the spell states:

> As a bonus action on each of your turns before the spell ends, you can change *the direction in which the line blasts from you*.

I don't think it could be much more explicit.

Comment: You might also want to quote the relevant section of the [*gust of wind*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gust-of-wind) description that the asker seems to have misquoted, which seems to be the basis of their confusion: "As a bonus action on each of your turns before the spell ends, you can change **the direction in which the line blasts from you**."

Comment: This is what I get for using the first google result and not taking the time to look it up in the PHB.

Comment: It happens. At the very least, this Q/A should help anybody else who stumbles on that same Google result.